# How does the default definition of (<*>) in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, the default implementation of the `(<*>)` operator (it applies an applicative of functions `a->b` to an applicative of `a` resulting in an applicative of `b`) in Control.Applicative is defined as such-

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) = liftA2 id
```

and I simply can't understand how it works.

`liftA2` has the type `liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`, meaning it takes a binary function, which `id` is not. From my understanding, this means `id` is somehow interpreted as some more complex type- but I'm not sure which or how it makes this definition work. If someone could explain perhaps what type is `id` interpreted as (what type the `a` in the `id :: a -> a` definition stands for) and also walk through how it results in a function which takes an applicative of functions and an applicative of values and applies them I would be very thankful.

Comment: `->` is right associative. `a -> b -> c` means `a -> (b -> c)`.

Comment: Note that `($)=id`, only with a less general type. That code can be written more clearly as `ap = liftA2 ($)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's say the type of `id` is `d -> d`, so all our type variables have different names. Now let's introduce two new type variables `e` and `t` and say that `d = e -> t`. That makes the type of `id`:

```
id :: (e -> t) -> e -> t
```

Now this fits the type of the first argument to `liftA2` with `a = e -> t`, `b = e` and `c = t`. So with those assignments, the type of `liftA2` becomes:

```
liftA2 :: ((e -> t) -> e -> t) -> f (e -> t) -> f e -> f t
```

And if we apply the first argument, the remaining type becomes `f (e -> t) -> f e -> f t`, which is exactly the type of `<*>` (modulo renaming).

Comment: Should that be `a = e -> t` rather than `a = e -> e`

Comment: @kimsagro Yes, it should. Fixed. Thank you.